# Presentation Tier does not contain a definition for 'Table' error (Creating an N-Tier Data Application in Visual Studio 2010 )

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to learn C# and ASP.NET. I intend to create an N-Tier Data Application. I followed the suggested 'WalkThrough' example for Visual Studio 2010 on:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384570(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384570%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

When I get to the 2nd last step, the 'Add DataGrid views to the form' step, am instructed to put the following code in the Form Event handler:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client DataSvc = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
northwindDataSet.Customers.Merge(DataSvc.GetCustomers());
northwindDataSet.Orders.Merge(DataSvc.GetOrders());
```

Which I do as shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PresentationTier
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         ServiceReference1.Service1Client DataSvc = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
         northwindDataSet.Customers.Merge(DataSvc.GetCustomers());
         northwindDataSet.Orders.Merge(DataSvc.GetOrders()); 
        }

    }
}
```

I however keep getting this error whenever I build the Solution:

PresentationTier.northwindDataSet' does not contain a definition for 'Customers'
PresentationTier.northwindDataSet' does not contain a definition for 'Orders'

I really don't understand why I get this error, yet I keenly followed the example step by step and have double checked if I did as instructed step by step.

Comment: I'd say your problem is that you followed the tutorial step by step, without knowing what you are doing. For instance, you don't know how to use the Object Browser or even just IntelliSense fo find out what's inside of `northwindDataSet`.

Comment: By the way, are you under the impression that VS2010 is the latest version of Visual Studio? Not only is that an old version, but it's an old technique. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686137.aspx.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @JohnSaunders.True,I did not put much thought into understanding the steps while I did them. I am using VS2010 because it's the tool I have available to me currently. The link you suggested is helpful too thank you. Could you probably point me to a 'full' tutorial that would use a more recent technique. The task I would ideally want to achieve is to have a simple form connected to a sql server  database, and use this form to perform CRUD operations on the database. Thanx again

Comment: I would never suggest that you use a tutorial. I would suggest you take a course or read a book. Tutorials are of no value to people who don't understand the basics yet. They are intended to impart _incremental_ knowledge to people who already understand the language and how to program.

Comment: @JohnSanders, I was afraid you would advise that haha. But you're probably right, I shouldn't be looking for shortcuts and learn the language the right way. Are there any C# or ASP.NET books that you might recommend? Something that might give me relevant skill in a week's time.

Comment: Silly me, there was a spelling error in my DataSet name. That's why it couldn't pick up the tables. Can't believe it's taken me this long to figure that out